# How to define complex routes with named parameters in express.js?

Tags: express

I want to set up some more complex routes that can include a number of optional parameters. Preferably, I would like to use named parameters for ease of access. Here is an example of what I'm trying to achieve:

```
// The following routes should be matched based on parameters provided:
// GET /books/:category/:author
// GET /books/:category/:author/limit/:limit
// GET /books/:category/:author/skip/:skip
// GET /books/:category/:author/limit/:limit/skip/:skip
// GET /books/:category/:author/sort/:sortby
// GET /books/:category/:author/sort/:sortby/limit/:limit
// GET /books/:category/:author/sort/:sortby/skip/:skip
// GET /books/:category/:author/sort/:sortby/limit/:limit/skip/:skip
app.get('/books/:category/:author/(sort/:sortby)?/(limit/:limit)?/(skip/:skip)?', myController.index);
```

As you can see, I'm trying to group the optional parameters with `(paramKey/paramValue)?`. That way I was hoping to be able to "mix and match" the optional parameters while still making use of the parameter naming. Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to work.

Is there any way to get this working without having to write straight regular expressions and adding additional logic to parse any resulting index-based parameter groups?

Basically, I'm looking for an easy way to parse key/value pairs from the route.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It looks like you want to re-implement the query string using the URL path.  My guess is that if you really wanted that, yes, you would have to write your own parsing/interpreting logic. AFAIK express path parameters are positional, whereas the query string is not.  Just use a query string and express will parse it for you automatically.

```
/books?category=sports&author=jack&limit=15?sortby=title
```

That will enable you to do

```
req.query.sortby
```

You may be able to get express to do 1/2 of the parsing for you with a regular expression path like `(:key/:value)*` or something along those lines (that will match multiple key/value pairs), but express isn't going to then further parse those results for you.

Comment: Thanks, that's kind of what I expected but I wanted to make sure that I wasn't missing anything. Support for a more user/SEO friendly url format with the same flexibility as the standard query string would definitely be a nice feature. Maybe sometime in the future :)

Comment: It should be `req.query.sortby`?

Comment: @PeterLyons I must be missing something, but where can I find the description of the syntax for the possible express route strings? Even such a basic thing as optional parameters is hidden in express docs, leave alone more complicated cases. I almost resorted to regexp matching when I've found about optional parameters... Thanks.

Comment: Read the code. The route non-regex strings are convenience methods intended for the simple cases like "/user/:id". If you can't make them work, just use a true RegExp that expresses your desired semantics.  https://github.com/visionmedia/express/blob/8d21f1e45c5149600b7eb00734a7eee6e90677a8/lib/utils.js#L262

Answer (score 6):

you can send data to view as follow:

```
//in the server side ...
 app.get('/search/:qkey/:qvalue', function(req, res){
    res.write(JSON.stringify({
      qkey:req.params.qkey;
      qvalue:req.params.qvalue;
    }));
 });
```

and in the client side... call to ajax

```
$.ajax({
  type:"POST",
  url:"/search/"+qkey+"/"+qvalue,
  success: function(data){
    var string = eval("(" + data + ")");
    //you access to server response with
    console.log(string.qkey+" and "+ string.qvalue);
  }
});
```

Comment: This isn't going to work because you are adding a GET handler in Express, yet sending a POST from the browser - a rather small bug. Other than that, it gets my upvote.

Comment: Never, ever for any reason, ever use `eval` ... haven't you read The Good Parts?

Comment: Um.. don't believe everything you read.  There are plenty times to use eval, or it would be deprecated. This is definitely not one of them though. 

If you use res.send instead of res.write, the response will be sent as JSON - you don't needs to stringify on the server or parse on the client.  If you must use res.write, then JSON.parse is better than eval here.