# Can't get correct route value in nodejs?

Tags: node.js

What am I doing wrong in my code here since I can't get the 'qkey' value?

If I test '/search/firstname/daniel' in my browser, my response is: {"qkey":"daniel"}

```
app.get('/search/:qkey/:qvalue', function(req, res){
    var qkey = req.params.qkey;
    var qvalue = req.params.qvalue;
    var query = {qkey:qvalue}
    console.log(query);
    res.send(query);
});
```

Comment: Think this should answer your question. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6010921/how-to-define-complex-routes-with-named-parameters-in-express-js

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is the way you create `query` object. You can't assign a dynamic value to a property name using curly bracket syntax. What you should do instead is;

```
var query = {};
query[qkey] = qvalue;
```

Comment: Thanks alot for the help! This was a great "christmas present"! :)

Answer (score 0):

you can send data to view as follow:

```
//in the server side ...
 app.get('/search/:qkey/:qvalue', function(req, res){
    res.write(JSON.stringify({
      qkey:req.params.qkey;
      qvalue:req.params.qvalue;
    }));
 });
```

and in the client side... call to ajax

```
$.ajax({
  type:"POST",
  url:"/search/"+qkey+"/"+qvalue,
  success: function(data){
    var string = eval("(" + data + ")");
    //you access to server response with
    console.log(string.qkey+" and "+ string.qvalue);
  }
});
```